# Resque Worker: Objects and methods not available in worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, resque-scheduler

I have the following worker in my web app

```
class TweetSender
    @queue = :tweets_queue 

        def self.perform(tweet_id)
            message = Tweet.where(:status_id => 0).order(:created_at, :id).limit(1)
            message.update_attribute(status_id = 1)
            $client.update(message.text)

        end
end
```

It gets schedueled by the following resque-scheduler tweet_scheduler.yml

tweet_sender:

```
  cron: "0 20 * * * Europe/Stockholm"
  class: "TweetSender"
  queue: tweets_queue
  args: tweet_id
  description: "This job sends daily tweets from the content db"
```

Which gets defined by he resque.rake

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'
task 'resque:setup' => :environment

namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'


  end

  task :setup_schedule => :setup do
    require 'resque-scheduler'
    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file('tweet_schedule.yml')
    require 'jobs'
end
task :scheduler => :setup_schedule
end
```

In the resque web interface I get the following error

```
Exception
NoMethodError
Error
undefined method `update_attribute' for #<Tweet::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x839ca814>
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
/home/jan/Documents/social/app/jobs/tweet_sender.rb:6:in `perform'
```

I alos tried implementing the tweet_sender.rb without the update_atttribute methods like so:

```
class TweetSender
    @queue = :tweets_queue 

        def self.perform(tweet_id)
            message = Tweet.where(:status_id => 0).order(:created_at, :id).limit(1)
            message.status_id = 1
            message.save
            $client.update(message.text)

        end
end
```

And the get the following error:

```
Exception
NoMethodError
Error
undefined method `status_id=' for #<Tweet::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x83195bf8>
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
/home/jan/Documents/social/app/jobs/tweet_sender.rb:6:in `perform'
```

Why are my methods and the standard rails emthods no available in my worker? Do I need to explicitly require them somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`limit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-limit) returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

What you really want to get is an instance of `Tweet` model.

Use [`first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first):

```
message = Tweet.where(status_id: 0).order(:created_at, :id).first
```

Comment: thank you, that makes sense.
I still get he error though
''Exception
NoMethodError
Error
undefined method `status_id=' for nil:NilClass
/home/jan/Documents/social/app/jobs/tweet_sender.rb:6:in `perform''
Now it wont even recognize the class. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jan it means that `first` returned you `nil`, meaning, there is no results satisfying your query conditions.

Comment: @AndreyDeneiko you are right, did not have the corresponding entry in my database! Thank you

Comment: Hash rockets are deprecated, please don’t use them while answering questions in 2017 :)

Comment: @mudasobwa never ever have I used hash rocket with symbol key :) It was just a copypaste of OP's code.

Comment: So for everybody learning. Instead of cryptic beginner unfriendly comments that should be the updated code: `message = Tweet.where(status_id: 0).order(:created_at, :id).first`